# How can we make an object serializable in java manually without implementing Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serialization

Serialization is defined as the converting and object to the byte array. Here, I am able to convert
the object to the byte array but still while storing the byte array(of given object) to the file, i am getting exception of object is not serializable. could anyone please explain me on it. Thanks!
The way i am using to convert the object to byte array is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(**yourObject**);
  out.flush();
  byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
  ...
} finally {
  try {
    bos.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    // ignore close exception
  }
}
```

Comment: *i am getting exception of object is not serializable* - well make it serializable

Comment: Make it implement `Serializable`, of course, or `Externalizable`. There is no other option. NB Serialization is defined as converting an object to a byte *stream.*

Answer (score 1):

In order to make an object serializable you have to make it implement the `Serializable` interface

Comment: My Question is, i have not implemented Serializable interface to the class. now i want to make any one object of the class serializable. is it possible to achieve that?